# How to scale PBR material so it doesn't look repeating

Tags: materials, uv, pbr

I'm trying to scale the material applied to the cube. Regardless if I scale it up or down, the pattern seems to look repeating. How can I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I see. The addon indeed doesn't work on symmetrical patterns like you said. This tiling effect happens when the object is too big compared to the texture's resolution. This will easily be solved if you have a higher resolution of the texture (probably 4k).

This happens to me as well. Given my limited resources, the way I would approach this is:

1. Instead of having 1 massive object(a cube in this instance), I would create a metal plate according to commercial dimensions.
2. Like the image below, I used array and played with UV offsets until desired pattern is achieved. (I added spaces between the object to show my point) You can also rearrange the objects by stacking arrays to add randomness.

[image]

PS. It's a little hard work but this is what I would do.

Cheers!