# Addon for generating diamond plate type of surface?

Tags: materials, add-on

Is there an addon for this type of shape? I need to create an industrial floor. I tried with PBR materials, but when I scale it, the pattern tile repeats itself and looks incorrect. I also bought an addon to fix the tiling issue but it doesn't work when the pattern needs to be immaculate.

[image]

Comment: Hi :). This is easily done with a normal map. The one included in [this material works fine](https://ambientcg.com/view?id=DiamondPlate001) and without visible tiling :))

Comment: It is not clear whether you want to use it as real geometry or as a shader. please add more information

Comment: Here's some more information: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/261359/how-to-scale-pbr-material-so-it-doesnt-look-repeating/261363#261363

Comment: I've made [a procedural diamond plate texture](https://imgur.com/4UhIxu7).. you can find the .blend [here](https://pasteall.org/blend/6bd95a163ac0451b87bbb05998025461)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just combine a [diamond pattern normal map](https://ambientcg.com/view?id=DiamondPlate003) with an [organic texture](https://ambientcg.com/view?id=Metal026) on top.

1. Scale the normal map to your needs
2. Add the organic texture with [BlenderGuru's Ubermapping Node](https://youtu.be/-VgtSL5ZpYc) to scale without tiling
3. Done

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the node set up!